# how to find the number of addressable locations and word size

Tags: memory, byte, cpu, cpu-architecture, word-size

For the following memory ICs, find the number of addressable locations and word size (contents of each
location:
1KB, 4K x 16 bits, 4MB, 4M x 32 bits

I was expecting to use the formula 2^n where n is addressable location

Comment: The formula you are referencing, V = B ^ N, tells use how many different values, V, we can have in a number base, B, using N digits.  So, V = 2^N applies to binary digits (i.e. bits).

Comment: Sometimes we have N and need to compute V, while other times we have V and need to compute N, which you can do by trial and error, lookup in textbook/online reference.

Comment: Further, the reverse formula is N = LogB(V), so for binary digits, N = Log2(V).

Comment: Fun fact, LogB(V) = Log10(V) / Log10(B), so if you only have log10 you can still compute Log2 (just divide by Log10(2)); same is true for natural log, ln, aka logE.